# selinux: how to enable httpd to have read-write and execute permissions

Tags: apache-http-server, selinux

I am facing problems with PHP interface that calls perl and shell scripts. These enable uploading of a file to a folder and execute them with some input while storing output into some other files. Now it appears that I can either give read-write access or execute using one of the following:

```
chcon -Rv --type=httpd_sys_rw_content_t user_dir/
chcon -Rv --type=httpd_fastcgi_script_exec_t user_dir/
```

How can I enable a folder recursively to have read-write and execute permissions? It appears that only one of the two contexts are effective. With the first an executable is being created by the compiler but cannot run, whereas with the second version the compilation also is not possible.

Comment: You are already applying it recursively, that's what the -R does. But selinux goes on top of normal file permissions like read-write and execute.

Can you post the result of these commands run in user_dir :

 
ls -Z


 ls -l

Comment: It appears only the last of the two is in force. With `httpd_sys_rw_content_t` being last, the output file is created with no content (as the executable could not run) and with `httpd_fastcgi_script_exec_t` the compilation does not take place.